# Unable to navigate to Docker container

Tags: docker

I built a container with a react app within it.

I start the app.. `docker run -p 3000:3000 blarg3/node`

I can bash into the container and curl localhost:3000 and it returns the front page of my site.

When I go to the IP and port http://172.17.0.2:3000/. Nothing is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default "docker run" binds port only to local interface. If you want to bind it to another interface you need to specify it's IP address like this:

```
docker run -p 172.17.0.2:3000:3000 blarg3/node
```

You can read more about docker networking options here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#connect-using-network-port-mapping